# How to find a list of rows where start & end almost matches a time?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a table containing some time presences, like this :

```
presences (id, account_id, start, end, date);
```

And here's some entries :

```
1, 1, 10:00:00, 11:00:00, 2013-07-02
2, 2, 10:05:00, 11:05:00, 2013-07-02
3, 3, 9:55:00, 11:10:00, 2013-07-02
4, 4, 10:02:00, 10:58:00, 2013-07-02
5, 1, 14:00:00, 15:30:00, 2013-07-02
6, 2, 14:03:00, 15:36:00, 2013-07-02
7, 3, 13:56:00, 15:28:00, 2013-07-02
8, 4, 14:05:00, 15:30:00, 2013-07-02
```

As you can see, the accounts have a `start` and `end` time **around** 10-11/14-15h, but it's not always exactly the same, so I cannot search `WHERE start = 14:00:00 AND end = 15:30:00` for example.

For the query, I have the date and the values of a single row (id: 1), and I like MySQL to return me all the presences that have the *same date*, is *not {id}* and have *start and end in that same range of time*

So far, I have this implementation, but I'm looking for a better way (if it exists) to match the results :

I get the middle time of `start + (end - start / 2)` (for id:1, this means 10:30:00), and I search like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM presences 
WHERE id != 1 
  AND start < 10:30:00 AND end > 10:30:00 
  AND date = 2013-07-02
```

`id` and `date` are the values found from the query (`SELECT * FROM presences WHERE id = 1`), and `start` and `end` are computed as explained before.

Is there a better way to found similar times ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM presences p cross join
     (select p.* from presences p where id = 1
     ) p1
where p.id <> p1.id and
      p.date = p1.date and
      p.start < p1.start + (p1.end - p1.start / 2) and
      p.end >  p1.start + (p1.end - p1.start / 2)
```

If you want any overlapping, then use this logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM presences p cross join
     (select p.* from presences p where id = 1
     ) p1
where p.id <> p1.id and
      p.date = p1.date and
      (p.start < p1.end and
       p.end > p1.start
      )
```

If you want start and end in the range, then look for that explicitly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM presences p cross join
     (select p.* from presences p where id = 1
     ) p1
where p.id <> p1.id and
      p.date = p1.date and
      p.start between p1.start + p1.end and
      p.end between p1.start + p1.end
```

You could add/subtract a few minutes from `p1.start` and `p1.end` to make the match fuzzier.

Comment: Your second option may not works if I take id = 3 for example